# Go to first empty cell after selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement a code, where if you click a certain cell; you go to the first empty cell in a certain column.

Now I have this code:

```
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Columns("E").Find(vbNullString, Cells(Rows.Count, "E")).Select
    End If
End If
```

But there is a problem with this code: I want it to start checking the first empty cell; starting at row 3. How do I do this?

**Edit1:**

I have made some adjustments to the code to fit my needs (for practice and aesthetics);

```
Dim lastCell As Range
Set lastCell = Range("E:E").Find(vbNullString, [E3], , , , xlNext)

lastCell.Interior.Color = RGB(100, 200, 100)
lastCell.Offset(0, -3) = "Last Cell -->"
lastCell.Offset(0, -3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 110, 250)
lastCell.Offset(0, -3).Font.Color = vbWhite

If Not Intersect(Target, [B2]) Is Nothing Then
    lastCell.Select
```

**Side Note**
The reason for Offset three columns to the right is because of the lay-out of the sheet :)
I clear the formatting of the cell and the text somewhere else if lastCell is changed. So if anyone is interested, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-write your code like this, just by supplying `SearchDirection` argument.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Columns("E").Find(vbNullString, Cells(Rows.Count, "E") _
            , , , , xlPrevious).Select
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Or you can try this one:

**Edit1:** For brettdj :)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Goto errhandler
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, [B2]) Is Nothing Then _
        Range("E:E").Find(vbNullString, [E3], , , , xlNext).Select
End If
continue:
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub
errhandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume continue

End Sub
```

Both code works the same way except if there are blank cells in between E3:E(x).
Your revise code finds the first empty cell in Column E with reference to the last non empty cell.
 
The next code literally finds the first empty cell from `E3`. Don't know which is really what you need.

**Side Notes:**

`Columns("E")` is the same as `Range("E:E")`.
Why use `Range("E:E")` then? Well, `Intellisense` kicks in with `Range` and not with `Columns`.
So I prefer using `Range` so you can see all the available arguments of `.Find` method.

Comment: Thanks! The second one works for what I am trying to do. Now on to the next problem; haha!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
  Dim maxrows&, iRow&, iCol&, zcell As Range
  maxrows = Excel.Rows.Count
  If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    iRow = Target.Row
    iCol = Target.Column
    Set zcell = Range(Cells(3, iCol), Cells(maxrows, iCol)).Find(vbNullString)
    zcell.Select
  End If
```